# Converter Int para String

Tags: java, swing, conversão-de-tipo

Estou tentando fazer um botão para cadastro ao banco mas estou tendo dificuldades em converter o int para String.

segue minha linha de código:

```
 private void jBtnCadastroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
       f = new Funcionario(String.valueOf(jtxtFuncionario.getText()),
                jTxtDepartamento.getText());

       jtxtFuncionario.setText("");
        jTxtDepartamento.setText("");

    f.Save();
    }
```

na linha " `f = new Funcionario(String.valueOf(jtxtFuncionario.getText())`" aparece o seguinte erro:

> string cannot be converted to string

Answer (score 1):

O método [`getText()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText--), conforme a própria documentação diz, retorna um tipo `String`, logo, não é necessário fazer cast para string.

```
f = new Funcionario(jtxtFuncionario.getText());
```

Se você estiver passando valores inteiros para um campo de texto, pro java isso não faz diferença, pois o método tratará todo o conteúdo como String. Se sua classe espera obter um inteiro, então o cast correto seria para int e nao para string:

```
f = new Funcionario(Integer.valueOf(jtxtFuncionario.getText()));
```

Comment: Perdão meu amigo primeiramente, a mensagem é "string cannot be converted to Integer"

Comment: @Edmundo o erro não condiz com o codigo. Edite a pergunta e forneça um **[mcve]** pois pelo código apresentado, a resposta soluciona o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Bom de Acordo com esse trecho do código:

f = new Funcionario(String.valueOf(jtxtFuncionario.getText()),
                jTxtDepartamento.getText());

você está tentando pegar a parte String de um campo de texto, o que está errado, pois mesmo que você ponha números no campo de texto o você vai 'pegar' um tipo String, então esse "String.ValueOf" é descartável.

Agora se você estiver tentando converter String em Integer você pode fazer o seguinte:

String texto = jtxtFuncionario.getText();
int textoInt = Integer.ParseInt(texto);

Answer (score 0):

Não é necessário realizar a conversão do objeto para String, uma vez que o retorno de:

```
jtxtFuncionario.getText()
```

Já é uma String!

Caso necessite realizar a conversão dessa objeto String para um Integer, pode escrever a seguinte linha de código:

```
Integer.valueOf(suaVariavelString);
```

Essa linha irá realizar a conversão de uma string em inteiro. é valido ressaltar que caracteres não inteiros, poderão gerar erros. Tenha a devida atenção para realizar a verificação da entrada de dados na sua tela (Mascara)

OBS: Tenha atenção a objetos nulos, geralmente ocasionam erros.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i =10;
    String inteiro;

    inteiro = i + "";
```

Esse é o jeito mais simples de fazer isso